# Como borrar un texto de un archivo en Linux

Tags: linux

Tengo que borrar un correo electronico de un archivo llamdo Email_Recepients.

He visto varios foros donde me dan sugerancias pero no veo que el correo se borre.

Esto es lo que he tratado hasta el momento:

```
sed '/test123@test.org/d' ./Email_Recepients
```

Comment: En el comando tienes una coma en vez de un punto en el email, es esto correcto?

Comment: Tienes razon, ya lo corregi. Era un punto. Al usarlo no funciona

Comment: sed manda el resultado a stdout y no cambia el archivo input.  Puede usar sed -I '/test123@test.org/d' ./Email_Recipients para cambiar el archive directamente.

Answer (score 0):

prueba con

```
sed -i 's/test123@test.org//g' ./Email_Recepients
```

La línea de código lo que en un principio hace es cambiar una cadena por otra. Aquí le hemos quitado la cadena de sustitución y entonces borra la original y no la sustituye por nada. La he probado y a mi me funciona.

Saludos